# Encoding a binary tree structure to json format

Tags: python, data-structures, encoding, binary-tree

I have a python binary tree class like this:

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.data
```

and I have tree traversal function like this:

```
  def tree_traversal(tree):
        if tree:
            for node_data in tree_traversal(tree.left):
                yield node_data
            for node_data in tree_traversal(tree.right):
                yield node_data
```

now I'm getting stuck in generating a data format like the below nested structure:

```
{'id':1,children:[{'id':2, children:[{'id':3, 'id':4}]}]}
```

the tree structure is:

```
1

|

2

(left)3 (right)4
```

Comment: I don't see any question here…

Comment: what is the problem you are encountering, exactly?

Comment: I'm getting stuck in generating json data format for the tree structure.

Comment: The JSON structure you are proposing is ambiguous.  In your example JSON, how do we know whether 2 is the left or the right child of 1?  And is there a reason you want the word 'children' in the JSON?

Answer (score 4):

What you'll need to do is to make your class serializable into a data structure of dictionaries and strings. I didn't find any general way of doing this, so what I usually do is make the BinaryTree implement some sort of  or "flattening" and "parsing" function. A good way of doing this is this:

```
import json

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def flatten(self):
        return {
            "data" : self.data, 
            "left" : self.left.flatten() if self.left else None,
            "right" : self.right.flatten() if self.right else None,
        }

    @classmethod
    def from_dictionary(cls, d):
        obj = cls(d["data"])

        if d.has_key("left") and d["left"] is not None:
            obj.left = cls.from_dictionary(d["left"])

        if d.has_key("right") and d["right"] is not None:
            obj.right = cls.from_dictionary(d["right"])

        return obj

if __name__ == "__main__":
    binary_tree = BinaryTree.from_dictionary({"data": "hello", "left": {"data" :  "yo"}})
    json_data = json.dumps(binary_tree.flatten())
    print "JSON: %s" % json_data
    binary_tree_from_json = BinaryTree.from_dictionary(json.loads(json_data))

    print binary_tree_from_json.data
    print binary_tree_from_json.left.data
```

Answer (score 2):

what value do you want to hold in each node? if it is just an int as your example showed, it should be easy enough:

a node has an id, one or more children, and a value:

```
{
"1" : { "children" : ["2"] ,     "value" : 1111 },
"2" : { "children" : ["3","4"] , "value" : 2222 },
"3" : { "children" : null ,      "value" : 3333 },
"4" : { "children" : null ,      "value" : 4444 }
}
```

Comment: Actually I have a tree structure as BinaryTree class defined, and I have a tree object created. But now I'm facing a problem of "encoding" the structure into json format so I can use javascript lib to present it.

Comment: That's not his question. He needs to create a serializable data structure from the BinaryTree.

Comment: @RonReiter Oh yeah, sorry I missed his point, I have edited the answer to better provide a possible JSON structure that is easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with stack, you can see code below.

```
"""
@param root: The root of binary tree.
@return: Preorder in list which contains node values.
"""
def preorderTraversal(self, root):
    if root is None:
        return []
    stack = [root]
    preorder = []
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        preorder.append(node.val)
        if node.right:
            stack.append(node.right)
        if node.left:
            stack.append(node.left)
    return preorder
```